# Get all fields that belong to a collection of entries

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, has-many

I have a model called `Entry` which has many `fields` (`fields` is another table, with the model `Field` and with `entry_id` as one of it's columns - linked to the `Entry` model by the [hasMany relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations)):

```
class Entry extends \Eloquent {
    public function fields() {
        return $this -> hasMany('Field');
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get all the fields that belong to a collection for entries, but if I try

```
Entry::where('form_id', $formId) -> fields
// There are multiple entries for each form_id
```

it throws up an error

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$fields
```

Trying to do it on the collection doesn't work either

```
Entry::where('form_id', $formId) -> get() -> fields

Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$fields
```

Trying the same for just the first record, works as expected

```
Entry::where('form_id', $formId) -> first() -> fields
```

So, is there an eloquent way to do this?

For now, all I can think of is looping through all the entries and manually merging their fields, or something like

```
$entries = Entry::where('form_id', $formId) -> get();
$entryIDs = array();
foreach($entries as $entry) {
    $entryIDs [] = $entry -> id;
}
$fields = Field::whereIn('entry_id', $entryIDs);
```

Comment: You need only `id`s of those fields?

Comment: @deczo, No, I need multiple columns from the field table, basically the collection of fields for all selected entries

Comment: Check my answer, if that's not the case let me know and I'll show you a bit longer solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your relations are like this: `Form` hasMany (or hasOne) `Entry` hasMany `Field`, right?
So you can use a shorthand, that Eloquent provides, for what you are trying to do:

```
// Form model
public function fields()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough('Field', 'Entry');
}
```

This way you get all the fields you want providing the Form model, as easy as this:

```
$fields = Form::find($formId)->fields; // Collection of Field models
```

---

Add constraints to the fields:

```
$fields = Form::find($formId)->fields() // return query builder object...
               ->where('entry_id', '=', 'value')  // ... so you can chain any builder method
               ->orderBy('something') // for example order by
               ->get();               // don't forget to return results with get()
```

---

edit 2

The easiest way to get both fields and entries, according to your comment, would be:

1 Load fields that match outer `where` and entry for each fields matching the inner `where` clause:

```
$fields = $form->fields()->where('x','=','value') // filter fields
              ->with(['entry' => function ($q) use ($entriesConstraint) {
                   $q->where('entriesColumn', '=', $entriesConstraint);
              }])->get();
```

2 Load fields that match outer `where` and have related entry matching inner `where` (and entry for each field):

```
$fields = $form->fields()->where('x','=','value') // filter fields
              ->whereHas('entry', function ($q) use ($entriesConstraint) {
                   $q->where('entriesColumn', '=', $entriesConstraint);
              })->with('entry')
              ->get();
```

---

`whereHas` and `with` mix:

```
User::whereHas('categories', function ($q) {

   $q->where('name','like','%lo%');  // first constraint to fetch entries
})->with(['categories'=>function($q){

   $q->where('name','like','%o%')    // another constraint for processing related model
     ->selectRaw('categories.id as id,avg(categories.id) as avg')   // raw for fancy aggregate
     ->groupBy('category_user.user_id');   // group by for aggregate
}])->get();
```

Comment: Nice. Is there someway that I can filter the entries based on other parameters as well? I understand `hasManyThrough` will give me all the fields for all the entries belonging to a form, but I need to get all the fields of only a particular set of entries. Thanks

Comment: Of course, it works just the same as any other relation, so simply use query builder methods. Check the edit in a sec.

Comment: How about filtering the entries themselves?
I'm actually trying to get all entries whose fields match certain criterion. I'll also need to apply other filters, orderBy, etc on the set of entries themselves.

Comment: That depends. You want to fetch the entries, the fields of some entries or both? Give me some example code you'd like, so it's clear on what you need.

Comment: A bit of both, I actually need something like: 
`Entry::where('form_id', $formId) -> where('a', 'value1') -> fields() -> where('x', 'test') -> where('y', '<>', 'test2')  -> entries()` 
or `Form::find($formId) -> fields() -> where('x', 'test') -> where('y', '<>', 'test2') -> entries() -> where('a', 'value1')`. 
Thanks

Comment: Thank you @deczo, but is there someway that I can get the collection of entries for these fields? (How do I extract all the entries from `$fields` ?)

Comment: No straightforward way to do this, so instead fetch fields like I showed and entries the same way. Why you need collections of both anyway?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to allow users to to query entries by their field values and then perform more actions on those entries, for example, let us say an entry as three types of fields A, B and C, I'd like the user to be able to get the average of A from all entries where fields with type B have a value greater than some value and A is less than another value and C matches yet another condition.
The actual use case is a bit more complex, but I was hoping there was a simple and efficient way to query deeply nested eloquent relationships.

Comment: As the other answers suggested, I could do `$entries = $fields -> get() -> lists('entry')`, but that gives me an array of Entries that I cannot build queries upon, like `$entries -> where('A', 'value') -> fields()` - I need to be able to access fields on the entry that didn't match the original query on the fields and thus are not a part of `$fields`

Comment: `Entry::whereHas(..)->with('fields')` returns just what you need - only entries that have particular fields, but with all their related fields. From what you are saying it seems enough. If not show the real example (complex or not).

Comment: Awesome, you're right. Now, would there be someway that I could query the fields of these entries further, say to get the average of the values of a fields matching certain conditions from these entries? Something like: 
`Entry::whereHas(..)->with('fields') -> get() -> lists('fields') -> where('col1', 'value1') -> avg('col2')`

Thanks!

Comment: Check my last edit, there's some of imaginary code that should make it clear. Otherwise can't help you anymore without real use case.

Comment: That makes it very clear. Thank you very much for all your help and patience.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

Get all/specified entries and eager load the fields, then loop over them

```
$fields = Entry::with(['fields'])->where('form_id', $formId)->get()->lists('fields');

foreach ($fields AS $field) { var_dump($field->toArray()); }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Entry::where('form_id', $formId) -> fields
```

should we rewritten has follow:

```
$entries = Entry::where('form_id', $formId)->with('fields')->get();
```

You will have a collection of Entry with their fields. You can use `lists` after, has Dane said.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you're trying to select a single column and get the result as an array.

It looks like QueryBuilder has a way of doing this

```
$roles = DB::table('roles')->lists('title');
```

But Eloquent doesn't seem to, at least not out of the box. However, you could take your Collection, use `->toArray()`, and then PHP's [array_column](http://php.net/array_column) if you're using PHP >= 5.5.0

Comment: Thanks, but not really. Let's say, from your example of users and roles, where each user can have many roles, I am trying to get all the roles that a particular group of users have. Or you can say, I'm trying to get the entire collection of roles that belong to a given group of users.